# How to build sipdroid in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I downloaded sipdroid project from [here](https://github.com/sunnyqeen/sipdroid) and tried to import in Android Studio. While building error:

> Error: NDK integration is deprecated in the current plugin.  Consider trying the new experimental plugin.  For details, see http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental.  Set "android.useDeprecatedNdk=true" in gradle.properties to continue using the current NDK integration.`

I created file with name `gradle.properties` and added `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true`

Then while building I had errors with including libs, for example:

`#include <myinttypes.h>`
`#include <spandsp/telephony.h>`
`#include <spandsp/g722.h>`
`#include <spandsp/private/g722.h>`

And one more error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users....\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

What's wrong? How to build project without this errors?

Comment: If you want to use a complex piece of software, you will likely have to either follow its existing build process used by its developers, or else invest a lot of time in creating a new one which starts with understanding the existing one.  You can't just blindly import such projects into an IDE and expect them to build.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you always can build jni-part with command line, doing this way:

```
$ export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=/opt/umake/AndroidStudioProjects/Sipdroid/app/src/main
$ /opt/umake/android/android-ndk/ndk-build
```

and create gradle.properties file with

```
android.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

at the root of the project.

And with new *build.gradle* (Module: app) will be this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.sipdroid.sipua"
        minSdkVersion 5
        targetSdkVersion 21

        ndk {
            moduleName "OSNetworkSystem"
        }
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = [] // disable automatic ndk-build call, which ignore our Android.mk
    sourceSets.main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```

*Its works for me.*

Usually I use Experimental Android Gradle Plugin, it much better for native projects. After import *sipdroid* to Android Studio you need to change *build.gradle* (Module: app) to this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 21
        buildToolsVersion = "21.0.1"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "org.sipdroid.sipua"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 10
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 21
        }
    }
    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    /*
     * native build settings
     */
    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "OSNetworkSystem"
        /*
         * Other ndk flags configurable here are
         * cppFlags.add("-fno-rtti")
         * cppFlags.add("-fno-exceptions")
         * ldLibs.addAll(["android", "log"])
         * stl       = "system"
         */
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
        // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
        }
        // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
        create("all")
    }
}
```

and change classpath in build.gradle (whole project, root directory) from

```
 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

to

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
```

and delete gradle.properties file with *'android.useDeprecatedNdk=true'* at the root of the project.

After build Android Studio will eliminate with *Gradle Build Messages* lots of errors in sources with includes, and locate them by clicking at corresponding message.

I don't see any other variants with Experimental Android Gradle Plugin, rather than to change includes in cpp and c-files like this:

Such as in *ndk/silk/src/SKP_Silk_main_FIX.h*:

```
#include "SKP_Silk_typedef.h"
```

to

```
#include "../interface/SKP_Silk_typedef.h"
```

It's sad that this fragment synch with Gradle Experimental Plugin gratefully, but hasn't effect.

```
android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There is the solution from
[How to use custom Android.mk with new gradle build system](http://How%20to%20use%20custom%20Android.mk%20with%20new%20gradle%20build%20system)

```
android.sources{
    main.jni {
        source {
            srcDirs = []
        }
    }
    main.jniLibs {
        source {
            srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
        }
    }
}
```

It seems a *bug* in plugin *gradle-experimental:0.4.0* throws this error

```
BError:Attempt to read a write only view of model of type 'java.lang.Object' given to rule 'model.android.sources'
```

but *gradle-experimental:0.3.0-alpha7* works fine if remove **jni** and save only **libs** directory.

Comment: Why not use `cppFlags.add("-I../interface")`?

Comment: It's a good idea, we can add that flags for all directories from Android.mk.